# Javascript: Static - undefined

Tags: javascript

i try with the static method to define more than one variables, but got still the following Error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navbar')`

```
export default class Dropdown {
    static options = {
        navbar: '.main-navbar'
    }
    init () {
        this._navbar = document.querySelector(this.options.navbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dropdown.options.navbar` as its static

Answer (score 0):

When calling a static variables from a class, instead of using `this`, you need to use the class name

```js
// This will fail
class ClassName {
  static varName = 'Static'
  constructor() { console.log('Static: ' + this.varName) }
}
new ClassName()
```

```js
// This will work
class ClassName {
  static varName = 'Static'
  constructor() { console.log('Static: ' + ClassName.varName) }
}
new ClassName()
```

Comment: And if i have more variables it will looks like this ? 

`static varName = '..';
static varName2 = '--';
static varName3 = 'sds';`

Comment: Yes, It will look like that